# Mapping Lucene search results with a relational database

Tags: java, search, lucene

I have an application which holds a list of documents. These documents are
indexed using Lucene.
I can search on keywords of the documents. I loop the TopDocs and get the
ID field (of each Lucene doc) which is related to the ID column in my
relational database. From all these ID's, I create a list.
After building the list of ID's, I make a database query which is executing
the following SELECT statement (JPA):

```
SELECT d From Document WHERE id IN (##list of ID's retrieved from Lucene##)
```

This list of document is sent to the view (GUI).

But, some documents are private and should not be in the list. Therefore,
we have some extra statements in the SELECT query to do some security
checks:

```
SELECT d From Document WHERE id IN (##list of ID's retrieved from Lucene##)
AND rule1 = foo
AND rule2 = bar
```

But now I'm wondering: I'm using the speed of Lucene to quickly search
documents, but I still have to do the SELECT query. So I'm loosing
performance on this one :-( ...
Does Lucene have some component which does this mapping for you? Or are
there any best practices on this issue? How do big projects map the Lucene
results to the relation database? Because the view should be rendering the
results?

Many thanks!

Jochen

Comment: What kind of performance hit are you worried about taking?  Lucene is for indexing, ideally you're going to have a database or file system of some underneath that.  If the relational database underneath Lucene is the appropriate choice for the rest of your system, what you're describe is the correct way to do things.

Comment: Well, I thought I could use Lucene so I didn't need a single MySQL query. Just fetch all Document attributes/details from the Lucene index. But because of the extra checks, we need to perform an extra MySQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- In Lucene, you can use a [Filter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Filter.html) to narrow down the search result according to your rules.
- Store the primary key or a unique key (an ID, a serial number, etc.) in Lucene. Then, your relational database can make unique key lookups and make things very fast.
- Lucene can act as storage of your documents too. If applicable in your case, you just retrieve the individual documents' content from Lucene and don't need to go to your relational database.

Comment: Can Lucene store a Java object? Because you are telling me: "Lucene can act as storage of your documents too". Document.java is a class holding some attributes of my actual document (PDF, TXT, ...). I think you are referring to a textual representation of a document, not the Java object ...

Comment: Yes. For each field of each document, Lucene can store the field's content as either a Java String or a byte array. See [the Field class's javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html). If you have some flat text (e.g. plain text or HTML), Lucene can store it as a String. Or, if you have a Java Object, you can serialize it (e.g. using ObjectOutputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream) into a byte array, and Lucene can store the byte array. Then, at search-time, once you have the document ID and field name, you can ask Lucene for the String/byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use lucene to index the table in the database? That way you can do everything in 1 lucene query.

Comment: Security restrictions are not in 1 single table. Security rules are spread in my database (into other tables - I'm sorry, my initial post doesn't make that very clear). If all rules would be on the Document table, yes, then I could store the rules and perform a single Lucene query

Answer (score 0):

if this is a big issue maybe it's worth looking at [ManifoldCF](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity/#Manifold_CF_.28Connector_Framework.29) that supports document level security that might fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Persimmonium, interesting! :-)